# More powerful word for unnecessary with the following connotations

Tags: synonyms

Want to describe `unnecessary <noun>` (ex: unnecessary stress), need something more appropriate which is synonymous with `unnecessary` but also has the following connotations.

1. unwanted
2. useless
3. unwarranted
4. Something which should not be there in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider *gratuitous* =

> (of something such as bad behaviour) not necessary, or with no cause
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gratuitous)

Answer (score 0):

Another word that might work is [superfluous](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/superfluous):

> More than is wanted or is sufficient; rendered unnecessary by superabundance; unnecessary; useless; excessive; as, a superfluous price.